# sed substitute with partial string

Tags: regex, linux, sed

```
echo "/c/test/my0.txt" | sed 's/.\{5\}$/.\{4\}$/g'
```

Is it possible to replace the last 5 characters of the line with the last 4 characters of the line in sed?

My filenames can be any length but the end is always predictable i.e. the part I want to substitute is always 5 characters from the end

Comment: with a capture group and a backreference: `sed 's/.\(.\{4\}\)$/\1/'` ?

Comment: Thanks! That's good for going back a large amount of characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just match them separately, and omit the undesired character:

```
echo "/c/test/my0.txt" | sed 's/.\(....\)$/\1/'
```

Another approach to what you seem to be after: You could explicitly target **the last character before the filename suffix**; this would work correctly even if the suffix had more, or fewer, characters (`.mpeg`, `.c`, `.txt~`, etc.)

```
echo "/c/test/my0.txt~" | sed 's/.\.\([^.][^.]*\)$/.\1/'
```

With `sed -E` (recommended), you can use the standard "modern" regular expressions and write the last one as:

```
echo "/c/test/my0.txt~" | sed -E 's/.\.([^.]+)$/.\1/'
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great.

Comment: That's interesting. Would there be any difference between `([^.]+)` and `(.*)`

Comment: Of course-- they differ in whether they match the empty string, and whether they include dots in the match. Read the regexp documentation.